# Using scope in model to manage views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 3.2.18
Ruby 2.1.5
```

In my models/event.rb, I have:

```
has_many :registrants
```

In my models/registrant.rb, I have:

```
belongs_to :event
```

The registrant model has the following fields in it:

```
event_id
status
```

In my controllers/registrants_controller.rb, I have:

```
def index
  @events = Event.all
```

So,then in my views/events/index.html.erb, I can use something like:

```
<% @events.each do |event| %>
  <% event.registrants.each do |registrant| %>  
    ....
```

How do I use scope in my model to limit the event.registrants to only those registrants who have a status of 'active'? I know that there may be other ways to do it, but I am trying to learn how to use scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

model:

```
class Registrant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  scope :active, -> { where(status: 'active') }
end
```

view:

```
<% @events.each do |event| %>
  <% event.registrants.active.each do |registrant| %>
```

Comment: This works and it clarifies the scope syntax for me. I will accept the answer as soon as stackoverflow allows me